# Pipe All AKS microservices into a single Application Insights and be able to filter by microservice name

Tags: azure, kubernetes, microservices, azure-application-insights

I would like to know if it is possible to have multiple Azure Kubernetes micro services pointing to the same Application Insights Resources and be able to use Log Queries to split the logs per micro services name.

At the moment, I have been able to create an Application Insights resource. I also configured the micro services to point to that Application Insights resource using Visual Studio 2017 IDE (all done via a GUI).

That being said, I now have all my micro services linked to the same Application Insights. I would like to be able to filter my log queries by micro service.

The reason behind this is that the company I work for might soon have a lot of micro services and do not want to manage N application insights resources. Instead, we want everything centralized in the same Application Insights (so I cannot use the union operator to join multiple application insights since we only want to have one).

I thought about adding custom fields to Application Insights, but it does not seem like it can help in my situation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/custom-fields

Thanks!

UPDATE: 
Sample code:
[image: Telemetry Clas]
Program.cs:
[image]
Custom dimensions:
[image]

After reading this post: [Adding Custom Dimension to Request Telemetry - Azure functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57073603/adding-custom-dimension-to-request-telemetry-azure-functions) I realized that I need to call TrackEvent(), TrackTrace(), etc. in order to see the new custom dimensions entry. However, I needed to add a Microservice column to any request/event/trace produced by a given microservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to fix the issue by adding some steps to the solution Peter gave me.

1. I created a custom telemetry initializer that looks like the following:

```
 public class MicroserviceNameTelemetry : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        private string microserviceName;
        public MicroserviceNameTelemetry(string microserviceName)
        {
            this.microserviceName = microserviceName;
        }
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties["Microservice"] = microserviceName;
        }

    }
```

I then had to overwrite the default telemetry initializer in the Startup.cs (the step I added):

```
public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationInsights(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(configuration);
            services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MicroserviceNameTelemetry>((serviceProvider) => {
                return new MicroserviceNameTelemetry(configuration.GetSection("Microservice").GetValue<string>("name"));
            });
            // Enable K8s telemetry initializer            
           services.AddApplicationInsightsKubernetesEnricher();

            return services;
}
```

Comment: You did not *overwrite* the default initializer, you *added* a new one to the collection :-) Multiple initializers are possible, in fact, adding the sdk will install some by default, like the one that adds the custom property `AspNetCoreEnvironment`

Answer (score 3):

> The reason behind this is that the company I work fore might soon have a lot of micro services and do not want to manage N application insights resources. Instead, we want everything centralized in the same Application Insights (so I cannot use the union operator to join multiple application insights since we only want to have one)

Do mind that App Insights price model is mainly based on cost per GB of data ingested. The first couple of GB per month is free. So your solution might not be the most cost efficient.

> I thought about adding custom fields to Application Insights, but it does not seem like it can help in my situation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/custom-fields

For App Insights you could use custom properties. There are several ways to set them (using code!). One is to set them directly as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#defaults):

```cs
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;

var gameTelemetry = new TelemetryClient();
gameTelemetry.Context.GlobalProperties["Game"] = currentGame.Name;
// Now all telemetry will automatically be sent with the context property:
gameTelemetry.TrackEvent("WinGame");
```

Do mind that this method will only add properties to the telemetry created using the `TelemetryClient` instance!

the other one is using a [telemetry initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer):

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace MvcWebRole.Telemetry
{
  /*
   * Custom TelemetryInitializer that overrides the default SDK
   * behavior of treating response codes >= 400 as failed requests
   *
   */
  public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
  {
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        // Is this a TrackRequest() ?
        if (requestTelemetry == null) return;
        int code;
        bool parsed = Int32.TryParse(requestTelemetry.ResponseCode, out code);
        if (!parsed) return;
        if (code >= 400 && code < 500)
        {
            // If we set the Success property, the SDK won't change it:
            requestTelemetry.Success = true;

            // Allow us to filter these requests in the portal:
            requestTelemetry.Properties["Overridden400s"] = "true";
        }
        // else leave the SDK to set the Success property
    }
  }
}
```

I prefer this one as it will also apply to telemetry created by the framework, not only to custom telemetry created using your own code.

> I would like to know if it is possible to have multiple Azure Kubernetes micro services pointing to the same Application Insights Resources and be able to use Log Queries to split the logs per micro services name.

Now, there might already be something in place. All telemetry have properties like `cloud_Rolename` & `cloud_RoleInstance`:

```
requests
| project cloud_RoleInstance , cloud_RoleName
```

it will show the container name and pod name so that might already be good enough for you.

So, for example, this will show requests split by pod:

```
requests
| summarize count() by cloud_RoleName
```

If you use C# you could also add [this](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Kubernetes) package created by Microsoft that will attach a lot of AKS details to the telemetry like pod id, pod labels, replica set name etc.

Comment: Wow Thanks Peter! I think I will use the first solution you gave along with the cloud_RoleInstance and cloud_RoleName. I did not know we could create custom telemetry objects.

Comment: By they way, custom properties are added to the customDimensions field that is available to all telemetry types. Let me know if you have difficulties accessing them

Comment: Will do! Thanks for all the help

Comment: Okay so whenever I want to add a custom field I use telemetry.context.GlobalProperties[key]=value and it will be added to the customDimensions field in any entry in Log Analytics?

Comment: Yes. Personally I prefer to use telemetry initializers as they are nicely decoupled and reusable and a bit more powerful.

Comment: Good call I totally agree

Comment: I have a question about TelemetryClient. I did add the required code (besides the call to the TrackEvent method (I will add the code in the post). The TelemetryClient is created in a method that is called at the beginning of the main (I know the code looks terrible now, but I want to get it working first). However, it is not working (see picture for the content of the custom dimensions. I see that it tacked my asp env env variable (K8sDEV) so perhaps I can just add an env var that contains the microservice name?

Comment: @vitonimal Yeah that is because that method only applies to custom created telemetry as stated in the linked docs. I've updated my answer to make it more clear. Sorry I could updated it earlier but I was at a conference with only a mobile.

Comment: No need to be sorry you saved me so much time. Thank you a lot for your time